# Hibernate dynamic map mode alternatives for persisting simple java.util.Maps to tables?

Tags: java, hibernate

For my app I don't want any ORM tool to crawl my domain objects and try to infer a table/column structure.  Instead I have a simple HashMap that of key/value pairs that I want to convert into a row in a DB table and I want to return database queries results as lists of maps.

I've been using hibernate's dynamic-map mode, specifying entity-name mappings instead of class mappings.  For the most part it works, but hibernate seems to be quite heavy weight, especially when it comes to nested maps and lists.

I've looked into writing custom tupilizers or types, but they seem a little heavy weight too.

Do any other popular ORM/persistence libs support features similar to hibernates dynamic maps? I've looked a little bit at DataNucleus and iBatis, but couldn't seem to find a HashMap type mode.

Answer (score 2):

Why are you using hibernate if you're not using the mapping features?

Why not just use spring's JDBC features (or straight jdbc even) and write a RowMapper that transforms any row into a HashMap?  This can easily be accomplished using the ResultSetMetaData.

Comment: I am using the mappings for mapping field names to appropriate column/table names (using the hbm.xml files), reading query results out as maps is relatively easy, its the inserts/updates, type conversion, nested lists/maps, etc that hibernate has been helping out with, but I realize I'm way out of the 'sweet spot' for hibernate at this point, which is why I'm looking for an alternative.

Comment: Also, I'm trying to keep a bit of RDBMS independence, so hopefully the hibernate dialects are giving me a bit of that, probably not much though at this point.

Comment: ORMLite is another possibility as well.  It's lightweight, uses annotations for mapping (though not the JPA annotations).  I'm not 100% sure how to do queries and put them in a map though.  You'd have to investigate that.